# Query AD for SID using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, guid

I need to write a PowerShell script that queries the Active Directory for the SID/GUID of certain objects and finds the least available SID/GUID within a range.

I want to take the approach of querying the AD at once and populating an array with all SIDs and then sorting this array in increasing order. Then I'll initialize a variable with the lower limit of my SID range and compare with the array.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. How can I query the AD for all Objects and populate an array of SIDs from there?
2. How do I compare two SID values (they are in a very complex format)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Quest module for Active Directory](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) is pretty simple:

```
$sidarray = get-qaduser |
select samaccountname, sid | 
sort {[Regex]::Replace($_.sid, '\d+$',
{
     $args[0].Value.PadLeft(10, '0')
   })
 }
```

The you can find some match like this:

```
$sidmatching = $sidarray | ? { $_.sid -match '-1234$' }
```

Comment: sort sid is not sorting properly. and SID with last few characters as 111467 appears before 9877. I think it is only checking the first digit or soemthing

Comment: @user1534235 Edit my answer to sort in an numeric way for the last character afetr the '-'